# Get reason for login prompt when using asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an asp.net website using the SQL ASP.net membership system.  When users are logged in to the website and are inactive for 20 minutes, they get sent to the login page on the next page request.  I would like to show some text on the login page that says "you were logged out due to inactivity" when this happens.  Is there a built-in way to do this?  Or any other ways I could distinguish why the user has been sent to the login page (for inactivity or some other reason)?  I have scoured SO and Google but haven't been able to come up with anything.

The reason we need to do this is because we recently migrated from a previous version of the website that was lax about security and didn't have auto logout, so we're getting lots of feedback from users thinking there's something wrong with the website when they are prompted to login again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For purposes of closure, I'll answer my own question.  I couldn't find a clean way of doing what I'd like, so I ended up setting a cookie with the login time after the user logs in.  Then on the login form page, I see if the login time in the cookie is greater than 30 minutes old (my auth timeout in asp.net) and display a "logged out due to inactivity" message.  Otherwise it doesn't display the message.

Not great, but it seems to work.  Satisfies the requirement for the vast majority of our users.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use javascript for this and be proactive about it, showing the timeout remaining if possible otherwise just alerting the user with a messagebox showing that his session has timed out and then redirecting him to the login page. Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Session_Timeout.aspx) for a simple example.

To redirect him to the login page add the following to the below line as in the example:

```
alert("Your current Session is over."); window.location = "YourLoginPage.aspx";
```

Comment: We've thought about this, but we can't always assume javascript is enabled.  We' like something on the actual login page if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: We are using in-process for the sessionstate mode.  I thought about  looking for the old session cookie when the new one is created, but I think it gets recycled if all the browser windows haven't been closed, so I don't think that would work.  How else could I use Session_End?  Thanks.

Comment: The problem with session_End is that it's a server side only trigger for cleaning resources, that's why I thought about it for a moment and removed the comment. I honestly can't think of anything else except normally when this happens the url will include a querystring with where it needs to be redirected back to, you can check if there is an actual redirect back to and then display some generic message to the user, but again the problem is you don't know if the user just wanted to access that page without logging in and the same thing is called